# Import from csv using WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to import some data from a csv file into a table in MySQL. The csv file and the table both have the same fields. What I want to do is update the values in the table in MySQL with the values in the csv file.I am trying to use the `WHERE` clause but what I have found I that, it does not fire on csv. Is it possible to do this? The condition in the where clause is that wherever the values of `field 1` in the two tables i.e .csv and MySQL is same, The values at `field 2` in the table should be updated.

Comment: I imagine you are trying to use something like this  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp. Can you please give an example of what sql query you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You surely can, but **only if** field1 is primary key. 
Consider following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
      `foo` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `bar` varchar(255),
      `baz` varchar(255),
      PRIMARY KEY (`foo`)
)
```

And assume that .csv file is as follows:

```
1,fred,wilma
1,john,doe
```

Then query should look like this:

```
mysql>LOAD DATA INFILE "/path/to/file.csv" REPLACE 
->INTO TABLE foo 
->FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 1  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from foo;
+-----+------+------+
| foo | bar  | baz  |
+-----+------+------+
|   1 | john | doe  |
+-----+------+------+
```

As you can see, the first line of imported file was replaced by the second one, because of the same value of primary key.